# HTML5 get date string convert to date object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I try to use html5 type="date" and get the string and convert it to Date() in JS.

```
var dateString = $(this).prev().val();
var date = new Date(dateString);

var day = date.getDay();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getYear();

finalDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
alert(finalDate);
```

But the result I got is different than what I've set, I have no idea what's wrong here :

[image]

I expect to get 18/05/1991

My demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/yL1q3ygf/

Comment: Check the DOC regarding Date object methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods  I guess no one can explain it better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var dateString = $(this).prev().val();
        var date = new Date(dateString);

        var day = date.getDate(); //day is for day of week. use date
        var month = date.getMonth() +1; // months are zero based
        var year = date.getFullYear(); //use full year for 4 digit year

        finalDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        alert(finalDate);

    });
});
```

I updated your jsfiddle script
http://jsfiddle.net/yL1q3ygf/5/

Answer (score 1):

getMonth() returns a number between 0 and 11. You want to use getMonth()+1.
getDay() returns the day of the week, you want to use getDate() instead.

Comment: And `getFullYear()` for the 4 digits ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `getUTCDate();` before making it as an object (date).

```
var d = new Date(dateString);
var n = d.getUTCDate();
```

then use n in your code. it will work